# If a civicase is reopened why isn't the Case Coordinator (and other roles) reinstated?

Tags: civicase

Client is wondering why when a Case is reopened it does not regain the Case Roles it had when it was closed.

Seems a fair enough question.

So perhaps the follow on question is - will a patch to fix this be accepted or will others  argue this may not be the desired outcome?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they used to stick around - maybe something changed recently. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to see what they were on closed cases. Question: When it was reopened was the start date changed? That might be a cause - the new start date being later than the relationship end date.

Comment: More info: See line 195 in https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Case/Form/Activity/ChangeCaseStatus.php. The code is still there to re-open them, so it's clearly intended to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A JIRA issue is now filed at https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21815 which provides this change into core.

Patch is at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11736 which should be a part of 4.7.32 release.