# Case Manager is not shown for closed cases

Tags: civicase, roles

I'm testing an upgrade from 4.6.38 to 5.5.3 and have noticed a new case related behavior that feels a little strange to me. When you close a case and subsequently the case roles expire and are disabled they no longer show on the manage case screen (in the roles section).

This issue prompted a PR that I think is the cause. [If a civicase is reopened why isn't the Case Coordinator (and other roles) reinstated?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/22932/if-a-civicase-is-reopened-why-isnt-the-case-coordinator-and-other-roles-reins)

I've not been in 4.7, so the verbiage 'reinstate' roles is confusing to me.  In 4.6.38, when a case was closed while the relationship may have been inactive but the case manager still showed on the case. As Demerit pointed out as a comment on that issue "I'm pretty sure they used to stick around - maybe something changed recently. Otherwise, you wouldn't be able to see what they were on closed cases."

I've verified on the demo site that if you close a case, case roles do, in fact, 'disappear' on the manage case screen. This is strange to me, why wouldn't you want to be able to reference who a case manager was on a closed case?

https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/commit/0fd841b07dfbb958a1c4ae8349131b3325b15dc4

In the PR, line 849 has, $activeOnly = TRUE. If I set that to FALSE, I can see case managers on closed cases. But I'm afraid that will have an effect beyond the manage case screen. Can this variable be set for just the manage case screen to "FALSE" so that you can still see Case Managers on closed cases?

Comment: Reinstate would just mean "make the role active again", but I agree that should be different from "role disappears from manage case when you close the case", which seems to have been a change that was introduced at some point, before that PR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is now a fix submitted on GitHub to handle this issue - https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/13144.

This should be a part of the next release, possibly 5.8.9.